# Detect if mips gcc supports __thread directive

Tags: gcc, mips, thread-local-storage

I am trying to compile QT for mips. My toolchain is a little old ( mips-linux-gcc --version is 4.1.0)

I am guessing this doesnt have the __thread directive. What version of gcc would I need?
Also is there a way to detect if my compiler supports this at compile time, so that if I upgrade my toolchain, I can seamlessly do so

Answer (score 1):

My copy of mips-linux-gcc version 4.5.3 supports the __thread directive. I don't know what version first supported it.